# Vuetify - Issue with styling v-bottom-nav content

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm pretty new to Vuetify.

I need a bottom navigation (or Footer for that sake), with a link I can format as I please.

I struggle with the v-bottom-nav only taking v-btn items, and the text only centers and are not styleable at all.

I have gone through a ton of examples and the documentation, and haven't found anything helpful; I'm guessing I have the wrong approach here.

**v-bottom-nav structure:**

```
<v-bottom-nav
                :value="true"
                absolute
                style="opacity:0.5"
              >
                <v-btn light>
                  <span>
                    Top 10 Australian beaches
                  </span>
                </v-btn>
              </v-bottom-nav>
```

Made a pen here:
[VUE Bottom Navigation tryout](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VgGVaa?editors=1010#anon-login)

Answer (score 0):

You can add scoped styling to your component - you may want to right click > "Inspect" your toolbar first to see what CSS you need to override, e.g.

```
<style scoped>
    .v-item-group.v-bottom-navigation .v-btn {
        color: red !important;
    }
</style>
```

[image]

More on scoped styles: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html

Also, consider adding attributes at the nav (rather than button) level, e.g.

```
<v-bottom-navigation
    color="primary"
    background-color="blue-grey lighten-5"
>
    <v-btn>
        <span>Top 10 beaches</span>
    </v-btn>
</v-bottom-navigation>
```